# X.509 Certificate Signature Collision Vulnerability

Tags: md5, x.509

Customer complained that during security scan performed on our application the following was raised:

```
172.22.0.19 - xxxxx - IETF X.509 Certificate Signature Collision Vulnerability - https/tcp/172.22.0.19/50000
```

The keystore (JKS format) has only one self signed certificate.

When I look at the keystore and certificate information I see the following: 
[image]

The signature algorithm is SHA1withRSA (not MD5), so why does the scan raised this problem? Is it related to the certificate fingerprints?

Thanks

Comment: The **fingerprints** are local, **not** in the SSL/TLS protocol at all, and can't be seen by any scanner. That said, I concur with Stephane; worrying about signature collision on selfsigned makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That really depends one what rules where used to trigger the warning and you gave us no information on that.

However, it is possible that your issue is that you have a certificate signed with SHA-1 which is being phased out. That being said, it doesn't make much sense: when using self-signed certificate (or root certificates), the hash is not actually ever used for validating anything.

So, you should go back to the folks who sent your that notification and ask them what they mean: if they start talking about the "certificate signature hash algorythm", you can tell them that it doesn't apply in your case since this is a self-signed cert.

**Edit**: As requested, here is a reference:

[RFC 5280, section 4.1.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.1.2) (the one defining the X.509v3 standard) defines the "signatureAlgorithm" field like this:

> The signatureAlgorithm field contains the identifier for the
> cryptographic algorithm used by the CA to sign this certificate.

This means that certificates that, in the case of certificates that are NOT signed by a CA (because they are CA certs or simply self-signed), this field has no meaning.

Comment: Yes, it's most likely that the rule that applied to MD5 was extended also to SHA-1 and you get this error.

Comment: Yup. But again, with a self-signed cert or a root CA, it doesn't matter AT ALL: the hash is never used. You could use a CRC without influencing the security

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can find this documented formally somewhere?

Comment: @danieln: documented what? If you ask about the error message, you need to ask whoever does the scans.

Comment: I Added a reference to the relevant RFC and explanation of why it's relevant

Comment: @Stephane: My "common sense" understanding is that whoever signs certificate signing requests is in fact playing a role of a CA. If this field has no meaning in case of a self-signed cert, what the signature verification algorithm is supposed to do?

Comment: That field tells you how you can verify the signature of the certificate. It only makes sense if you're using PKI to see if you can trust it. With self-signed certs (CA certs are also self-signed), this isn't how you check if a cert is to be trusted or not: you use the context for that (usually, the local certificate store).

Comment: So, again, in the case of self-signed certs, that field is simply not used. I don't know why it's even a mandatory field. I suspect it was initially a (naive) way to check if if certificate public key is actually valid (because you can still check the signature of the hash) and it was just kept for compatibility.

Comment: You say the field is not used, do you mean a signature is filled in but is irrelevant because the whole cert or its fingerprint is used for validity checking?

Comment: Yes, that's it.